# filter the hive complex data types

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

i created a table using hive i want to filter the data

```
create table student(
      id bigint
     ,name string
     , course array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMiTED fields terminated by '\t'
collection items terminated by ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

and data like

```
100 student1    java,.net,hadoop
101 student2    .net,hadoop
102 student3    java,hadoop
103 student4    .net,hadoop
104 student5    java,.net
105 student6    java,.net,hadoop
106 student7    .net,hadoop
```

> fiter this data based on cource = hadoop

please anyone help me.

Comment: **equal** or **contains**?

Comment: course datatype having above data, i want to filter the students which are doing hadoop course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  * 
from    student
where   array_contains (course,'hadoop')
;
```

---

```
+-----+----------+--------------------------+
| id  |   name   |          course          |
+-----+----------+--------------------------+
| 100 | student1 | ["java",".net","hadoop"] |
| 101 | student2 | [".net","hadoop"]        |
| 102 | student3 | ["java","hadoop"]        |
| 103 | student4 | [".net","hadoop"]        |
| 105 | student6 | ["java",".net","hadoop"] |
| 106 | student7 | [".net","hadoop"]        |
+-----+----------+--------------------------+
```